# Can't create IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I created a new microsoft account and activated an azure promo code / azure pass. It shows that I have 100$ left. Now I wanted to create a new IoT Hub same way as I normaly do. But when I try to select a price plan, it shows the following error message:

> {"Code":"UserSubscriptionIdNotFound","HttpStatusCode":"NotFound","Message":"Subscription not found: 99ca1d7f-b58f-4c2b-b14c-89dfa0167b41. If you contact a support representative please include this correlation identifier: 7f755989-3646-4880-9336-e65d9aa74428, timestamp: 2018-01-31 10:38:00Z, errorcode: IH404006."}

I tried to create a new Stream analytics and some other modules in my ressource-group an they work fine. So the subscription should be activated.

Comment: Same thing for me

Comment: You can use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#az_iot_hub_create) and have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if it still happening? A hotfix is released for Azure Portal, and in the meantime, CLI would always work.

Comment: It works now fine. But should not happen in a productive environment....

Answer (score 0):

*edit, going over my old posts: this problem was an issue at Microsoft's, and was fixed*

I also have the same problem. Just got into a long talk with Microsoft, and it looks like it is a problem with their servers.

Specifically, an access to the endpoint https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/. . .b/providers/Microsoft.Devices/usages?api-version=2017-07-01. . .

Let us see what happens next...

Answer (score 0):

If you just added a new subscription, I recommend you going to [Azure](https://account.azure.com/)  to see if there are new subscriptions under your account.

If yes, try to create IoT hub again, it should work already.

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed. The subscription was working fine but it was impossible to create the iot hub. Stream analytics, storage and all other modules worked fine.